# System Verilog number multiplication?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

How can I multiply by -1 in system Verilog? Inside an ALU?

I tried:

```
 logic [DPWIDTH-1:0] alu_result;
 always_comb
     case (alusel)
         ALU_REV: alu_result = alu_a * (-1);
     endcase
```

But for some reason it doesn't work as expected.

Comment: Please explain what you were expecting versus what you actually saw. It also helps to show declarations of all variables involved .

Comment: keep in mind that *alu_result* is **not** *signed* in our declaration.

Answer (score -1):

The first answer in my mind is:

```
alu_result = -alu_a;
```

But if you want to use multiplication you must use signed variables:

```
localparam logic signed [DPWIDTH/2-1:0] NEGATIVE_ONE_C = -1;
logic signed [DPWIDTH-1:0] alu_result;

always_comb begin
  case (alusel)
    ALU_REV: begin
      alu_result = signed'(alu_a) * NEGATIVE_ONE_C;
    end
  endcase
end
```

Instead of typecasting alu_a you should change its declaration, too.
Also, note the size of NEGATIVE_ONE_C.

Answer (score -1):

If you want just to store the variables as their negative in ALU. Then you can also use 2's complement method too store in bits.
`number = -number;`
or
`number = 'number + 1'b1;`

Answer (score -1):

I do not know the ALU structure and whether you use 1's or 2's complement you are using but if you are using 2's complement you can simply invert all bits and add 1 using your adder.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).